# Using Elementor Icons in own PHP files

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How can I use Elementor Icons in my PHP file?

Elementor generates following structure:

```
<a id="elementor-menu-cart__toggle_button" href="#" class="elementor-button elementor-size-sm">
    <span class="elementor-button-text"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>3.990,00</span></span>
    <span class="elementor-button-icon" data-counter="10">
        <i class="eicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="elementor-screen-only">Cart</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

If I use this structure in my own PHP files the icon is not showing. How can I use Elementor Icons in the right way?

The Icon I want to use:
[image]

It is Elementor or just WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

I believe elementor uses fontAwesome, in that case, you can just enqueue the style, 
add this to you functions.php file in your theme:

```
function use_elementor_icons() {
   wp_enqueue_style ( 'font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'use_elementor_icons()', 3);
```

Comment: Nope, the icon I want to use is not a FontAwesome Icon. Maybe is not Elementor? I mean the Shopping Bag icon from WooCommerce I used with an Elementor Widget.. I edited my first post with a screenshot.

Comment: can you share your custom code in how you are trying to use it?

Comment: The same as above. But the icon is not showing. FontAwesome Icons are working with `class="fa fa-heart"` for example. But this strange "eicon" icons are not working.